# How to overlay an image on top of another image using iMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

**Overview:**

I got two images. The background image with 1920x1080p resolution and the overlay image that can be of any resolution less than 1920x1080p.

**Background image(1920x1080):**

[image]

**Overlay image:(any size less <= 1920x1080)**

[image]

**Result image(1920x1080):**

[image]

I am trying to overlay the overlay image exactly at the center of background image. I know how to do it using ImageMagick.

**Solution using ImageMagick:**

```
convert -composite -gravity center background.png overlay.png result.png
```

**Expextation:**

I am expecting to do the same using iMagick with the help of `Imagick::compositeImage` and `gravity center`. So please any one can help me out here.

Comment: I think this might be a bug in ImageMagick. I have opened a bug upstream https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagick wraps the C-API [MagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) which doesn't automatically inherit the `-composite -gravity` behavior. You will need to do the math yourself.

```php
$background = new Imagick( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '6pEEG.png');
$window = new Imagick(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mpyY3.png');

$deltaX = $background->getImageWidth()  - $window->getImageWidth();
$deltaY = $background->getImageHeight() - $window->getImageHeight();

$background->compositeImage($window,
                            Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,
                            $deltaX / 2,
                            $deltaY / 2);
```

[image: How to overlay an image on top of another image using iMagick]