# How to overlay two images, one with transparent background in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have two pictures:

- first one is a foreground.png with a transparent background
- second one is a background.jpg

I would like to put them on top of each other in a way that the .jpg is "beneeth" and the .png "on top". So that the .jpg parts are only visible in the transparent parts of the .png.

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be you would like to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019244/how-to-overlay-an-image-on-top-of-another-image-using-imagick. If can put more details like what you have tried so people can help you better.

Comment: Yes, that has worked, thank you.